# Running a full node

Tags: tangle

Can someone explain to an average joe like me  how to run a node in the Tangle. Do I have to be an expert or somehow knowledgable about some kind of stuff? Or is it possible for the common people to do it??

Comment: http://iota.partners/index.html (while you don't need to, you really should understand all the commands issued there)

Answer (score 3):

As answered above you could go the route of using the AWS script. It's one of the current easiest routes right now.

Here's the full blog about it + some other methods:

https://medium.com/deviota/iota-nelson-ready-for-public-preview-a958c6d0a531

And here's another more detailed step-by-step guide for VPS:

https://forum.helloiota.com/2424/Setting-up-a-VPS-IOTA-Full-Node-from-scratch

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I ll try those links out! Super thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to set up and run a full node.
https://twitter.com/romansemko/status/943375376272764929?ref_src=twcamp%5Eshare%7Ctwsrc%5Eios%7Ctwgr%5Ejp.naver.line.Share